# Unable to call method of a different class from SmsReceiver

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I am working on an sms app on android the sender types and clicks send message the message is manipulated in a class Ecc and is sent to the receiver. The receiver has to read this message and send it to its Ecc class where manipulation is done on it and is sent back to the sender. I am able to send the message to the receiver but nothing happens at the receiver end.

here is the SmsReceiver class

```
 package com.example.smsTest;

 import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();
    Object[] messages=(Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
    SmsMessage[] sms=new SmsMessage[messages.length];

    Ecc ecc;
    ecc = new Ecc(context);
    String msg_receive = intent.getStringExtra("message1"); 
    if (msg_receive != null)  { 

    for(int n=0;n<messages.length;n++)
        {
            sms[n]=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);

        }

    for(SmsMessage msg:sms)
        {
            String ph=msg.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
            String body=msg.getMessageBody();
            ecc.recv(ph,body);          
            Toast.makeText(context,"ecc entered at receiver", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            SMSTest.update("\n From:" +ph+"\n"+"message:"+body+"\n");

            Toast.makeText(context,"updated", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }
  } 
}
```

here is the ecc class

```
package com.example.smsTest;
import java.util.*;
public class Ecc{

//code
private SMSTest smsTest;


// Constructor
public Ecc(SMSTest smsTest) {
    this.smsTest = smsTest;
}


public void recv(String phn, String smsg){

    String[] spl1=str.split("\\.");
 if("abc".equals(spl1[0])){
    //code
   sendSMS(ph,smsg)  
 }  
 if("pmg".equals(spl1[0])){
   //code 
sendSMS(ph,smsg)  
 }  
}

//code
//---sends a SMS message to another device---
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.DONUT)
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")    
    public void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
    {      
        /*
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, test.class), 0);                
            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);        
        */

        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(smsTest, 0,
            new Intent(SENT), 0);

        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(smsTest, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

        //---when the SMS has been sent---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(smsTest, "SMS sent", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(smsTest, "Generic failure", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(smsTest, "No service", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(smsTest, "Null PDU", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(smsTest, "Radio off", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

        //---when the SMS has been delivered---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.DONUT)
            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(smsTest, "SMS delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Toast.makeText(smsTest, "SMS not delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;                  
                }
            }
        },new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));        

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);               
    }

    private void registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver,
            IntentFilter intentFilter) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


 }
```

here is SMSTest class

```
package com.example.smsTest;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.DONUT)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class SMSTest extends Activity 
{
public final static String SMS_Message = "com.example.SMSTest.MESSAGE";
public final static String SMS_Phone = "com.example.SMSTest.MESSAGE";
static TextView txtmsg;
Button btnSendSMS;
EditText txtPhoneNo;
EditText txtMessage;
Ecc ecc; 

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    txtmsg=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtmsg);
    btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
    txtPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNo);
    txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);

    ecc=new Ecc(this);

    /*
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Content of the SMS goes here..."); 
    sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    startActivity(sendIntent);
    */

    btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {               
            String phoneNo = txtPhoneNo.getText().toString(); 
            String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();
            message="pmg."+message;
            if (phoneNo.length()>0 && message.length()>0){
                System.out.println("details verified");    
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Ecc call clicked", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ecc.recv(phoneNo, message);
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                    "Please enter both phone number and message.", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });


}

public static void update(String msg) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    txtmsg.append(msg);

}

}
```

Here is the manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.smsTest"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
      <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />


  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".SMSTest"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver"> 
        <intent-filter >
               <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

I dont get any errors. The sender side functions as i want it to the receiver gets the message but nothing happens.

Comment: post Ecc class code also

Comment: @prosper K: i still need help in making the message going into the ecc method

Comment: @prosper K: I made a few changes and I am getting the error i just updated can you tell me where the problem is

Comment: you need to move sendSMS method inside Ecc class and use context in place of `this` ,`getBaseContext()` which u are passing at the time of object creation of Ecc class in IntentService and Activity

Comment: Ecc doesnot extend activity it is a stand alone java file. How will the sendSMS method work there i get so many errors in it

Comment: @prosper K: i have no problem with the sms sending there is problem only with the receive

Comment: @prosper K: i did what you told still i get the same error

Comment: Rad plz add latest code of both class if u are getting still issue

Comment: I am not getting any issues any more but still the receiver side is not doing anything i am updating the post in a few mins

Comment: @prosper K: i have added the latest version of my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as in `Ecc` class :

```
// Constructor
public Ecc(SMSTest smsTest) {   //<<<<
    this.smsTest = smsTest;
}
```

you have created `Ecc` Constructor with `SMSTest` Activity type parameter but u are passing `SMSReceiver` to at time of object creation inside `BroadcastReceiver`

**Solution:**

instead of calling method of Activity by creating Activity instance make a separate normal java class for sharing methods between Activity or `BroadcastReceiver` . instead of passing any component instance pass Context for sending sms as :

```
Context context ;
    // Constructor
    public Ecc(Context context) {   //<<<<
        this.context = context;
    }
```

now use `context` for sending SMS and create  `Ecc` class instance inside `BroadcastReceiver` as :

```
Ecc ecc;
ecc=new Ecc(context);  //<< pass context instead of this
```

Comment: I did this i dont get any error now but the method is not being called. Do i have to trigger the Smsreceive every time with a button?

Comment: basically my SMSTest activity starts and sends a message to the receiver this message is available in the inbox and the Smsreceive class should send it back to ecc class this happens at the receiver end. I am testing with my single mobile as source and destination.

Comment: which method is not calling  ecc.rev()?

Comment: the ecc.recv method has to be called when a message is received but nothing happens

Comment: @Rad : because BroadcastReceiver  time is very less instead of calling  ecc.recv method from BroadcastReceiver you can start an IntentService and use same code instead IntentService . see [this](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-intentservice-example-using.html) example for starting IntentService from BroadcastReceiver

Comment: fine i will give it a try and get back

Comment: @prosper K I am unable to call the ecc context i defined like you explaind previosly.

Comment: @prosper K i posted the recent one i am not sure if i am doing it right

Comment: @prosper K: i still need help in making the message going into the ecc method

Comment: @Rad: ok tell me where u are facing issue

Comment: firstly the message is sent from the sender using the app i created. The app is also running at the receiver end. When the message with the padding of abc. is received at the receiver the Smsreceiver should send that message to the ecc.recv() method. That is not happining. I am not getting any errors but the app just stops there nothing happens

Comment: @posper K : I am also having problem in properly writing the things i need in the suggestion you gave me using the IntentService

Answer (score 0):

Please register your broadcast in Manifast file like this

```
<receiver android:name="your package name and class name">  </receiver>
```

or try to register your Broadcast in code instead of manifest like this

```
IntentFilter in_filter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
     Incoming = new BroadcastReceiver()
            {   
            @Override
            public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  {
                      telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                      callEventListener = new PhoneStateListener(){
                          public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                                super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
                                if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE){
                                     System.out.println("Idel State phone");
                                }
                                else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                                    context.stopService(new Intent(context, myPlayService.class));
                                    System.out.println("phone ringing");
                                }
                            }
                        };
                telephonyManager.listen(callEventListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
                      }
                 }
            };

            this.registerReceiver(Incoming, in_filter);
```